# ktor - resource (Unit' is deprecated. Please use `staticResources` instead), usage favicon.ico

Tags: ktor

The ktor 2.2.1 version was installed in the application, which had no problems with the following code:

```
routing {
        static("/static") {
            resources("static")
        }
        resource("favicon.ico")
}
```

After updating ktor to version 2.3.6, 3 warnings for "static", "resources" and "resource" appeared.
The first two warnings are successfully eliminated by using StaticResources. The following code is working successfully:

```
routing {
        resource("favicon.ico")
        staticResources("/static", "static")
}
```

When I try to replace the resource("favicon.ico") with a staticResource or staticFile, the warning disappears, but the icon stops displaying.

Many options have been tried before applying:

```
1) staticResources("/favicon.ico", "favicon.ico")
2) staticResources("/favicon.ico", null)
3) staticFiles("favicon.ico", File("favicon.ico"))
```

and so on through the list.
Placing favicon.ico in the main directory or adding it as an index to the main static resources also did not bring success.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no direct mapping from the deprecated API to the new one, but you can use the following code to achieve the same behavior as with `resource("favicon.ico")`:

```
get("/favicon.ico") {
    val favicon = call.resolveResource("favicon.ico")
    if (favicon != null) {
        call.respond(favicon)
    }
}
```